# How to add TRE to NITF image files in gdal?

Tags: c#, image, gdal

I'm trying to convert a Bitmap object to a NITF 2.1 (National Imagery Transmission Format) file and need to include a TRE (tagged record extension), specifically a SENSRB block.
How do you add a TRE to the dataset for a NITF file in gdal in an easy way?

I'm using the NuGet packages GDAL.NET/GDAL.NET.Core v2.3.1 and have succeded in writing a NITF file. I can also read the NITF file including any TRE blocks.

Reading works fine:

```
Dataset dsIn = Gdal.Open(infilepath, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
metadata = dsIn.GetMetadata("xml:TRE");
```

The variable metadata receives an xml-text block containing the TREs.
But writing in the same manner does not work:

```
DataSet dsOut = driver.CreateCopy(outfilePath, dsIn, 0, options, null, null);
dsOut.SetMetadata(metadata , "xml:TRE");
```

The xml block ends up in an external .aux.xml file, instead of inside the NITF file.

I managed to create a small TRE by specifying the explicit record in the options argument:

```
metadataStrings = new[] {"FILE_TRE=CCINFA=0012AS 17ge:GENC:3:3-5:AUS00000"};
var dsOut = _drvOut.CreateCopy(outfilePath, ds, 0, metadataStrings, null, null);
```

Which creates the CCINFA record inside the NITF-file. But then I would have to create the entire SENSRB-record, which is rather complex.

Have I missed something?

Comment: You are going to have to build the SENSRB at some point, and it is irreducible complexity. What were you hoping for?

Comment: I was hoping for easy interface which build the record based on the specification nitf_spec.xml. Now I had to write this myself and it took a couple days. It handles the padding and all required fields.

Comment: Note that SENSRB recently got more variations. I still haven't put those into the nitf_spec.xml.